# why use sqlalchemy declarative api?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

New to sqlalchemy and somewhat novice with programing and python.  I had wanted to query a table.  It seems I can use the all() function when querying but cannot filter without creating a class.

1.) Can I filter without creating a class and using the declarative api?  Is the filtering example stated below incorrect?
2.) When would it be appropriate to use declarative api in sqlalchemy and when would it not be appropriate?

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db = sql.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres')
engine = db.connect()
meta = MetaData(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session()

files = Table('files',meta,
Column('file_id',Integer,primary_key=True),
Column('file_name',String(256)),
Column('query',String(256)),
Column('results',Integer),
Column('totalresults',Integer),
schema='indeed')

session.query(files).all() #ok
session.query(files).filter(files.file_name = 'test.json') #not ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter by a `Table` construct, it should be:

```
session.query(files).filter(files.c.file_name == 'test.json')
```

You need to create mapped classes if you want to use the ORM features of SQLAlchemy. For example, with the code you currently have, in order to do an update you have to do

```
session.execute(files.update().values(...))
```

As opposed to:

```
file = session.query(File).first()
file.file_name = "new file name"
session.commit()
```

The declarative API happens to be the easiest way of constructing mapped classes, so use it if you want to use the ORM.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems that I would have to use `execute()`for `Table`/core constructs as I'm getting a 'keyword can't be an expression'.

Comment: @Jimmy "keyword can't be an expression" is a SyntaxError that indicates you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality comparison operator `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Filter using declarative api this way:

```
session.query(files).filter(files.file_name == 'test.json').all()
```

You can also use raw sql queries ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage)).

Whether using declarative api or not may depend on your queries complexity, because sometimes sqlalchemy doesn't optimize them right way.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems that declarative is the way to go as the expressions are simpler.  I would have to use `execute()` and type in raw sql otherwise.